# Is there a way to add an image to a tab page header?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add an image on window form using c#, but every implementation did not give the result I needed. I want the image stay on the navigation bar, but it always hop into the main tab. This is the code I'm currently using

```
public TabPage AddCustomTabs()
{
    TabPage imageTab = new TabPage();
    imageTab.Text = "";
    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"gameBarResources\kakumei.png");
    pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    // Add the picture box to the tab page
    imageTab.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

    // Add the tab page to the tab control
    _tabControl.TabPages.Add(imageTab);

    return imageTab;
}
```

[image: window form image]
The image supposed to be at the navigation bar (The pink area)

Comment: The tabs at the top are part of the TabControl, not the TabPage. There's no support for adding arbitrary images to the tabs in the standard control. I believe that you can add an icon but that's all. I can't check now but I think you can owner-draw the tabs, so you could look into that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so if I save a file as .ico file, there is a way right? can it be considered an icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an `ImageList` to your form and add it images. Set the image size.
2. Set the TabControl's `ImageList` property to your image list (e.g. `imageList1`).
3. Click on a tab page and set the `ImageIndex` or the `ImageKey` property. There is a drop-down in the properties window, where you can select an image from the ImageList.

You can also change the `ItemSize` of the TabControl. This defines the size of the tabs (header or navigation part of the tab page).

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will do what the OP wants. Unless I'm mistaken, the image will be displayed as an icon next to the text in a very small area rather than occupying the full tab, as they appear to want. Is that not the case?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, you can change the image size in the ImageList to override the default of 16 x 16 pixels. This allows you to create large images.

Comment: Don't they just get resized to maintain aspect ratio and displayed in an area that size anyway though? I'm on a phone and can't really check for myself but it was my impression that that was the case. I could well be wrong though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, the images are stretched to that size. So, it's best to use images of the same size to avoid distortions and blurring.